# Firebase offline storage with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, firebase

I am developing a Phongap application where which would be able to work offline and persist data even after closing application. Is this possible with Firebase?

Answer (score 4):

Firebase is online-only.

But you can of course integrate your own offline storage with Firebase's online storage. For more details on that, see this answer, where @Kato explains the basics of such an architecture: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815549/209103

Comment: Looks like Firebase now has offline capabilities: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has recently released offline support for Android & iOS SDKs.

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-29-announcing-mobile-offline-support.html

Comment: And webapp support as well via Firestore now.