# Backup Firebase data on persistent file storage on Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: angularjs, firebase, offline, angularfire, persistent

I looking for ideas how to implement a local backup of Firebase data on an users device for Cordova/PhoneGap apps.

So if an app is shut down, updated etc. the data can be booted from there.

There is one approach using local storage:
https://github.com/yeldarby/offline-firebase

However I prefer not to override Firebase code,
and to save data more persistently. Either written to a file via the Cordova file api, or via the SQLite Database plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap.

What is the best way to listen to changes on the Firebase data via AngularFire?
So I could react on it an save it along with the Firebase object keys etc.

And, Is there even a way to physically save pending local events?

Related:
[Firebase offline storage with Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514845/firebase-offline-storage-with-phonegap)

Comment: Why listen for changes on AngularFire instead of the Firebase SDK? AngularFire is a bindings library for synchronizing data between Angular views and Firebase, not suitable for implementing your own offline persistence lib.

Comment: Hi Kato. Yes you are right. The [on()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) method seems the right way to listen for changes.